# Reloading content after change of url with router

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, router

Lately I'm learning and trying to do chat app with react. Today I ve ran into a problem with react-router:

I'm using custom link (/string/:userid1/:userid2) which is supposed to show me chat between users and it works, but when i try to change chat to other IDs (other users) my page doesn't reload and it doesn't show me other chat untill i reload page manually.
The quesion is if there is any possibility to refresh component / page after clicking Link button

```
<Link to={`/chat/${params.myuid}/${friends.uid}`}><div className="text-center pt-3"><img className="friends-img" src={friends.url} alt=""/></div></Link>
```

Comment: You should have a corresponding route that detects that receives the url parameters. Please show relevant code. In case you're checking the url in the onMount handler, there's your answer why it doesn't detect the change.

Answer (score 1):

Try making the variables you get form the url a part of your page state.
I mean everytime it changed there should be a change in your state.
It may help you page re-render without a manual reload.
Tip: `useEffect with the route variables in the dependancy array.`

Comment: This is a good guess but it's too early to post an answer.